# Can test cases from test link be mapped to TFS?

Tags: tfs, testlink

In my project, I would like to map test cases directly from test link to TFS.
The test link version that I am using is 1.9.19

Answer (score 0):

You must have taken the following steps before you can map TestArchitect test cases with TFS test cases:

1) In the TestArchitect explorer tree, right-click the Test node, a test folder node, or a test module node containing the test cases to be mapped.

2) Select External Tool > Visual Studio > Map Test Cases.

3) In the Map Test Cases to Team Foundation Server dialog box, for each test case that you wish to have mapped to a TFS test case, enter the TFS test case ID into the Source column, then click OK.

[image]

**But, the main thing you have to manage that**

- Each TFS source ID can only be mapped to a single TestArchitect test case.
- If the TFS source ID has been mapped to another TestArchitect test case, that source ID is highlighted in red.
  [image]

4) Click OK.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this
can the test link be integrated in different tools?

Comment: Yes sure, Let me know if any concern

Comment: Hi, I could not see test architecture explorer tree in TFS or test link.

Comment: I think that TestArchitect is a different tool. The only integration method I could find in a quick search was to code to the APIs of TestLink and TFS. There is a migration utility at https://github.com/ashenwolf/testlink2tfs but it is 7 years old and may no longer work.